# s3 File Uploading is so slow C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I'm using the transferUtility class to upload files into S3 using input stream in .NET. The problem is, uploading a file of 4MB takes around a minute. I tried both transferUtility.Upload and S3Client.PutObject and the upload time didn't seem to change. The code is below:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;


this.S3Client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, endPoint);

this.transferUtility = new TransferUtility(this.S3Client);

Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtilityUploadRequest transferRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();

transferRequest.BucketName = s3Bucket;

transferRequest.CannedACL = Amazon.S3.S3CannedACL.PublicRead;


transferRequest.InputStream = (Stream)fileStream;

transferRequest.Key = newFileName;

transferRequest.Headers.Expires = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);

this.transferUtility.Upload(transferRequest);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Did you test the internet connection, to make sure that's not it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it in 2 different local servers and one remote server/ Nothing changed

Comment: What happens if you try a significantly smaller file (ex 200kb)? Does it still take a long time, or is it faster? What about an 8mb file? Does that take twice as long?

Comment: I have just tested uploading a 356kb excel file and it took 6 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is happening because of an uploading the file stream to the application server takes a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely also due to the C# SDK MD5sum'ing every chunk it uploads (CPU performance hit and thus slows down the upload while an MD5Sum is computed).

See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/832#issuecomment-383756520 for workaround.